# Equivalent form not using absolute values

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

Looking at the solution of Trench´s Introduction to Real Analysis exercises, I am struggling with this:

Write the following expression in equivalent form not involving absolute values:

$a + b + 2c + |a - b| + |a + b - 2c + |a - b||$

it uses the following solution

$(a)$ $a + b + |a - b| =  2\max(a, b)$

Let $\alpha=a + b + 2c + |a - b| + |a + b - 2c + |a - b||$

From $(a)$, $\alpha = 2[\max(a,b)+c+|\max(a,b)-c|] = df\beta$. From $(a)$ with $a$ and $b$ replaced by $max(a,b)$ and $c$, $\beta = 4\max(\max(a,b),c) = 4\max(a,b,c)$

what I don´t quite grasp is the $df\beta$ part that´s then changed to $\beta$, how do they come up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses part $(a)$, so for $2(\max(a,b)+c+|\max(a,b)-c|)$ Let $\max(a,b)=\delta$, then we have:

$\max(a,b)+c+|\max(a,b)-c|=\delta+c+|\delta-c|=2\max(\delta,c)$ (from $(a)$)

Thus:

$2(\max(a,b)+c+|\max(a,b)-c|)=2(2\max(\delta,c))=4\max(\delta,c)=4\max(\max(a,b),c)$

So in the end:

$\max(a,b)+c+|\max(a,b)-c|=4\max(\max(a,b),c)$.

Comment: Thank you very much ellya!

Comment: No worries, I find that bad notation, and not enough explanation gets the best of everyone.